# Shell Scripting - return to previous loop until process is completed then die/done

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am writing a bash/shell script to automate some file filtering functions. Here is what I have written so far. Its based of a script I found online.

```
if (( $(ps -ef | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
    echo "$service is not done" >> /root/test.txt
else
    (( $(wc -l /root/filter/first.txt) > 0 ))
    if (( $(ps -ef | grep $service | wc -l) < 0 ))
    then
        ./root/filter/filefilter.sh
    else (( $(ls | grep /root/filter/final.txt | wc -l) > 0 ))
        if (( $(ps -ef | grep awk | wc -l) > 0 ))
        then
            (( $(ls | grep /root/filter/final.txt | wc -l) > 0 ))
        else
            # here is where I would like it to loop until the filtering is complete
            # then once the final file is > 0 stop/die/done
        fi
    fi
fi
```

I would like it loop until the final.txt has been created in the dir, I will add that part in, just need assistance on the loop or return function ( if return can be used to return to line 1 and start running the script again until the final.txt is created then die/done/stop)

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and please indent your code.

Comment: As I mentioned I am new to coding and I do not know what you mean by indent, I followed the serverfault rules and made the code show up in the code box.

Comment: I do not need the code checked as the site you posted does, I need help coding it to loop back to line 1 until the final.txt is not empty then die/done/stop so unfortunately your link does not help me.

Comment: The code works for me but unless I want to do a cronjob it dies after running it and I have to keep running it until the process is done and is no longer listed.

Comment: I fixed the indentation. You also missed two closing parentheses, after the last two `wc -l`, which I added. You should use an editor which auto-indents and highlights parenthesis mismatches, that's how I found those two errors.

Comment: Also, what you're looking for is `while` instead of `if` on the first line. The man page for bash should tell you how it works.

Comment: you should probably be using `[ -s ` *`filename`* `]` for most of those `wc -l` tests,

Comment: Line #5  `(( $(wc -l /root/filter/first.txt) > 0 ))` needs a " < " after the "-l" or it would return two fields, (a number and a filename), also the test doesn't seem to be used in a compound command, perhaps this test was misplaced.  Line #6 tests for the impossible: `wc -l` could never print a _negative_ number.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand some parts of your code. 
1) Does the script filefilter.sh performs the filtering? 
2) If yes, in what condition will it filters (eg. $service exist)
3) Are you filtering selected services or all processes running

Indent is pretty important in scripting as you can easily spot the loops clearly

[ Your Code ]:

```
if (( $(ps -ef | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
    echo "$service is not done" >> /root/test.txt
else
    (( $(wc -l /root/filter/first.txt) > 0 ))        #There is no condition required for the else-loop

    if (( $(ps -ef | grep $service | wc -l) < 0 ))
    then
            ./root/filter/filefilter.sh

    else
        (( $(ls | grep /root/filter/final.txt | wc -l) > 0 ))   #There is no condition required for the else-loop

            if (( $(ps -ef | grep awk | wc -l) > 0 ))  
            then
                    (( $(ls | grep /root/filter/final.txt | wc -l) > 0 ))
            else
                    #You can use the exit command to stop the loop base on the condition you want

        fi
    fi
fi
```